# Need to display a validation error in related list custom button

Tags: visualforce, related-list, controller-extension

I have a **new contact** custom URL button in **Account related list** contact section. But we do have a requirement that user click on that new contact in account related list if account's Phone field empty then display a error like "This account does not have a phone. Please add it before create a contact"

I checked and there are few options we can implement this. One is

1. JavaScript code
2. VF page
3. LWC -not possible because we cannot add lwc as a related list button

Since JS is not a good in security perspective I will move with VF page. I a new to VF ,I created a page but that's not appear in list button section. Can anyone help me?

```visualforce
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactValidationExtension" action="{!validateAccountPhone}">
    <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

```apex
public with sharing class ContactValidationExtension {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    public ContactValidationExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.controller = stdController;
    }

    public PageReference validateAccountPhone() {
        Contact contactRecord = (Contact)controller.getRecord();

        if (contactRecord.AccountId == null) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error: No Account selected for the Contact.'));
            return null;
        }

        Account account = [SELECT Phone FROM Account WHERE Id = :contactRecord.AccountId];

        if (String.isBlank(account.Phone)) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error: The Account\'s Phone field cannot be empty. Please fill in the Account\'s Phone field before creating a Contact.'));
            return null;
        }

        return new PageReference('/001/e?accid=' + contactRecord.AccountId); // Redirect to Contact creation page with Account prepopulated
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @FelixvanHove, If i put Account the button is available in contact object button and action section and it will not come there. And I did not tried the suggest one let me have a try on that